# Bash: store find result in a variable bash in order to be used in ffmpeg command

Tags: bash

I use the following command to get the big file

```
find . -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -1
```

I want to store path to a variable and use it in ffmpeg command like:

```
ffmpeg -ss 600 -t 1 -i $bigfile -vcodec png -vframes 1 image.png
```

I see that %p contains ./bigfile.m2ts

How to achieve this and how to get full path to big file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the output of a command is relatively easy:

```
bigfile="$(find . -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -1 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //')"
```

And if you have a relative path, it's easy enough to make it absolute:

```
bigfile="${PWD}/$(find . -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -1 | sed 's/^[^ ]* //')"
```

This will give you something like `home/pax/./someDir/bigHonkinFile.ext` but that's still usable.

Note that I've added the extra `sed` to your pipeline to strip off the file size. You need that size to *sort* properly but it has no place in the filename string.

Comment: and it is possible to get fullpath to that big file ?

Comment: If you remove `%s`, the sort is not working correctly, it give me the smallest file instead of largest

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: @Snake, Freddy was right (and so are you). You need the size to sort but I think Freddy was suggesting getting rid of *after* the sort. I've adjusted the answer to do that.

Comment: @paxdiablo Are the double quotes absolutely necessary in an assignment like `bigfile=$(find ...)` ? I didn't think word splitting happened on the right hand side. Or is it a style thing? Thank you if you have a moment to indulge me.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, it's definitely a style thing. I tend to use quotes for all strings just in *case* they have spaces in them.